# Vundle: activate Jade highlighting?

Tags: vim, express, pug

Mac OSX 10.7, Vim 7.3

I have installed Vundle for Vim, and I have included these lines in my `~/.vimrc`:

```
Bundle "gmarik/vundle"
Bundle "pangloss/vim-javascript"
Bundle "https://github.com/digitaltoad/vim-jade.git"
```

I then run (in Vim): `:BundleInstall!`, and vim gives an agreeable `Done!` without mentioning any errors.

Javascript files are highlighted just fine.  But when I open a jade file (`express/views/index.jade`), I don't get any color highlighting love.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the name of the repository

```
Bundle 'digitaltoad/vim-jade'
```

Then

```
$vim +BundleInstall! +BundleClean +q
```

Reload vim. Just worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

For the new version of Vundle, add this to your `.vimrc`:

```
Plugin 'digitaltoad/vim-jade'
```

and run

```
:PluginInstall
```

that works for me.